# Official position of the title "Chazzan"

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader

My grandfather ז”ל (the Frankfurt connection) was a chazzan for much of his professional career. When he died several years back, I inherited his sifrei chazzanus and his cantorial levush (clothing). I have since noticed that often, especially in some of his older post-war seforim, the title of chazzan (abbreviated Ch. or CH.) is found between the personal and family names, similar (lehavdil) to the title of Cardinal in the Catholic world.

Why is the title of Chazzan positioned there in most written contexts from that time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title indicates it might be a German thing

Comment: Wikipedia says that the German title Graf was placed in that way. A better analogy than the one you used.

Comment: @sabbahillel, I'm not sure. Both titles in the OP refer to ecclesiastic roles (lehavdil) whereas *Graf* is completely secular.

Comment: I meant that it is still a way of stating a title and it would be less repugnant to use Graf as an example rather than the other. It seems that it is a general rule.

Comment: @sabbahillel Seems equally repugnant (equally zero, that is). Words and German grammar aren't repugnant.

Comment: I hope this isn't too personal, but, could you scan and upload a page where this is mentioned? I think this would be quite interesting. (I have a further interest in this, but I may have to arrange a chat with you on it.)

Comment: @DanF, bli neder, I'll do so sometime on Monday, my grandfather's chazzanus books are in a different town than I am currently.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm not sure that it's specifically German, my German sifrei chazzanus do not have this convention.